# In the "Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)" tutorial, as of Xcode 11.0 the Hello World Screen appears over the top of the canvas, hiding it

Tags: ios, swift

In April 2019 I got a third of the way through "Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)" and it was working fine. I recently updated to Xcode 11.0 and started from the beginning again. In the Build a basic UI section, It shows how to draw a Text Field, Button & Label on the canvas. But when I run it in the simulator, it shows the 3 elements for a second, but then the white Hello World screen is drawn over the top of the elements and they can't be seen.
How to I stop the Hello World Screen Appearing.

The Tutorial I'm referring to is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1

To get to this point I started a new Single View App and drew the 3 elements on the canvas in the file "LaunchScreen.storyboard", then compiled.

The Hello World screen is in a new file in the template called ContentView.swift which contains the below. The Tutorial was last updated December 2016 and Xcode has been updated many times since and the buttons are not as described, but I was able to find the functions using google. If anyone knows how to remove the Hello World Screen, that would be appreciated. I'm new to iOS development.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  FoodTracker2
//
//  Created by Steve on 25/9/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 FinestSites.net. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Finest you created a `SwiftUI` project which is different from `interface builder`. Both used to develop UI of the application.

As you mentioned you added elements in `LaunchScreen.storyboard` which is not correct.

`LaunchScreen.storyboard` is only presented only start of the application. Once the application is up and running it will be replaced by your main controller which in your case is `ContentView`. So it is performing the correct flow.

In the tutorial, it is using `interface builder`. So go and create a `new single view app` and uncheck `Use SwiftUI` as highlighted below.

[image]

After that locate `Main.storyboard` and add element into that viewController.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thanks for your help. The Xcode 11.0 interface is slightly different. There is a Drop down called User interface with the options SwiftUI or Storyboard. Using Storyboard worked. It was confusing the first time because the options here are so different from the tutorial now.